# How would I delay a task in java?

Tags: java, timer, delay

Let me preface this by saying I've ruled out swing timers. Is there a way to sleep the thread or something to delay a task by a certain time? This will be using graphics (JFrame, specifically.)

Thank you.

Comment: Did you google the phrase `Thread sleep Java` at all?

Comment: `I've ruled out swing timers.` Why? When working with Swing that is generally what you should use.